# apache web server deployment issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite

I have created my CMS on WordPress and expose it through wp-api to the world.

I have some doubts on that. Please help to figure out the solution for below queries.

1. Want to stop access of https://blog.domain-name.com or we can redirect to main site i.e. https://www..com for all upcoming request from anyone except below cases.
2. Want to give access wp-admin through specific ip address
3. Want to expose wp-api i.e. API endpoint to the world. For Example : https://blog.domain-name.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts can be accessed from any IP address.

Here is my .htaccess sample which I wrote

```
    ErrorDocument 401 /blog.example.local/index.php?error=404
    ErrorDocument 403 /blog.example.local/index.php?error=404

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/wp-admin$ 

    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=403]

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/wp-json(.*)$
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1  [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.local/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

   </IfModule>
   <files wp-config.php>
      order allow,deny
      Require all denied
   </files>
```

Everything is hosted on Linux server (AWS EC2 instance) and Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

I waited a lot to get the answer on this but still didn't get any response. So I started to modify the .htaccess file and reading all the apache rewrite rules.

Finally I got the answer successfully and it is working fine for me. I am posting answer here so that anyone can get reference if they will get issue in future.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^127.0.0.1$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-json(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1  [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-admin(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-json(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

<files wp-config.php>
 order allow,deny
 Require all denied
</files>
```